# SYSTEMD-FSTAB-GENERATOR unit service not starting

Tags: mount, fstab, automount

I have the following entry in /etc/fstab:

```
//remote/folder /mnt/local_folder cifs x-systemd.automount,uid=user,gid=user,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,ro 0 0
```

and it mounts fine, but the systemd unit automount service doesn't start. It appears to have created a `mnt-local_folder.automount` service and attempting to start it automatically fails with 'folder already mounted'. The workaround is to unmount the folder, and start the service that way and then the autmount works, but without this additional step if we lose connection to the remote server, it has to be mounted again manually. Is there an fstab config step I'm missing?
Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's the complete line? The comma in front of `x-systemd.automount` looks wrong ...

Comment: Good spot, but that was due to me removing one of the mount options from the post for readability. Looks fine in production (just removed from OP now).

Comment: When it comes to working with `fstab`, to heck with readability. *Completeness* is king 

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/fstab` line seems incomplete. There's nothing denoting the file system that is in use, nor is there an `auto` flag. I believe the line should look something like this:

```
//remote/folder /mnt/local_folder cifs auto,x-systemd.automount,uid=user,gid=user,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,ro 0 0
```

***Note:** Be sure to change `cifs` location to a different file system such as `smbfs` or whatnot if you are not using `cifs`.*

After saving the file, you will likely need to reload the daemon:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then finally restart the remote and local file system targets:

```
sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
sudo systemctl restart local-fs.target
```

With this, the remote device should be mounted as a read-only location and be active across reboots.

Comment: Sorry, yes, as with previous commenter, I'd  created an incomplete fstab entry in the post (now fixed). The share is being mounted okay, so the fstab entry is valid, I just don't understand why the automount service isn't started. It requires manually starting (whihc requires manually unmounting the share) or a server reboot, of course.

Comment: I'm still not seeing `auto` in your `fstab` line. I've updated the answer to include some additional steps that you've probably already done, but are important to note.